# suspend a shell command without pid

Tags: linux, shell

I need something like `$command & stop` This should execute a command and suspend it. The application later resumes back the command for complete results.

I understand that job can be suspended with stop signal to the corresponding pid.

```
$kill -SIGSTOP 12753
```

When we execute a command, we barely know its pid. There is extra command involved to take a pid and do the required. I want to avoid the extra command and a time interval.

Basically The application is for a measure of network performance. Trigger all the commands put them in halt mode. The halted commands are resumed back as per the kind of traffic needed.

Comment: Arjun, that is too manual. I need it as a script, as their are thousands of commands which needs to be put in stopped state as soon as executed.

Answer (score 2):

Kindly confirm if you want to halt your command or run in background(append '&' to your command)?

If your application is expected to start halted command later, then why dont you start your command(to be halted) in  that application itself.

This helps :

`sleep 5 & kill -SIGSTOP $!`

In above, have executed sleep(demo command) for 5 seconds in background.
Next have send to kill for stopping it using its PID obtained by $!.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265783/is-it-ok-to-use-an-answer-to-comment-if-you-lack-the-reputation-to-comment

Comment: Arjan, 2nd line is answer :)

Comment: @ Rohit Verma, Triggering a every new command as child is time taking. So i initiate all the required commands as a process first and come back later to activate it.

Comment: hey sandy_1111 you had the answer. `command & kill -SIGSTOP $!`

Comment: @RohitVerma although appealing, it's erroneous. what if command was echo "hi" ? then $! would be echo "hi".  kill needs the command name which  is rarely the command.

Comment: @BaroudiSafwene that's not the case. Its tested on ubuntu 14 terminal. It stops echo, you can check status using jobs command. Anyway its already answered/accepted by chepner

Comment: @RohitVerma you are absolutely right I have mistaken !! for $!, yes your solution works just fine for background jobs. thumbs up.

Answer (score 2):

The process ID of the most recently started background command is available in the shell parameter `$!`:

```
$ command & kill -SIGSTOP $!
```

(Check the documentation for your shell's implementation of `kill` for the correct format.)

Comment: thanks chepner, but this does not seem to work when we put in a script. first the -SIGSTOP gave error **run.sh: line 2: kill: SIGSTOP: invalid signal specification** used the numeric value of signal (19) the script ran fine but halted processes are not listed in `ps -eaf`

Comment: @WarrenYoung that's not right either. There's no background command anymore; `kill` won't run until the command completes, and who knows what `$!` is set to.

Comment: @chepner: You're right on the `&`, of course. As for `-STOP` instead of `-SIGSTOP`, both work on Linux or OS X, since they're running Bash, and you're using the Bash builtin in this case. You can also use `-s STOP` or `-s SIGSTOP` on these systems. All of this even seems to work with `/bin/kill`, too.

Comment: `dash` at least returns `Illegal option -S`, so the OP might be using some other shell that uses a different format.

Answer (score 1):

Try `killall` with the **--signal** option where you can specify the name of the process.

```
linux:~ # killall
Usage: killall [OPTION]... [--] NAME...
       killall -l, --list
       killall -V, --version

  -e,--exact          require exact match for very long names
  -I,--ignore-case    case insensitive process name match
  -g,--process-group  kill process group instead of process
  -i,--interactive    ask for confirmation before killing
  -l,--list           list all known signal names
  -q,--quiet          don't print complaints
  -r,--regexp         interpret NAME as an extended regular expression
  -s,--signal SIGNAL  send this signal instead of SIGTERM
  -u,--user USER      kill only process(es) running as USER
  -v,--verbose        report if the signal was successfully sent
  -V,--version        display version information
  -w,--wait           wait for processes to die
```

Verified by starting `md5sum` in a  shell session:

```
linux$ md5sum
```

and in another session, ran:

```
killall -s SIGSTOP md5sum
```

yielding the following in the `md5sum` session:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 md5sum
```

Comment: thanks bvj, but does `killall` command applies to all the relevant commands..?  **killall -s SIGSTOP md5sum** would stop all the running `md5sum`. Should extra care be taken to match a exact command using regular expression..?

Comment: @sandy_1111 It matches exact names, so `killall -s SIGSTOP md5` will not stop `md5sum`.

Comment: @sandy_1111  Well, you could have processes with identical names but might be different binaries distinguished by their respective paths. If you know where your commands live, you can parse the results of `ps -Af` to determine which processes you wish to suspend.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using the same command, find the command name in ps output, you can launch it in one terminal then open a new terminal

```
ps -ely
```

after retrieving the command name:

```
command & kill -SIGSTOP $(pidof command_name)
```

pidof needs the exact command name to be able to find the pid.

then to resume it:

```
kill -SIGCONT $(pidof command_name)
```

if the command name is not constant, but there is a pattern, you can create a script like this, you can call it pof.sh:

```
ps -ely | grep $1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f3

command &  kill -SIGSTOP $(bash pof.sh pattern)
```

One drawback with this script, is that in case many lines match the pattern it will returns all of theirs pids, if this is a problem, you can put the output in an array and go on from there.

Comment: what if the command is suppose to run in background..?   is it **command & && kill -SIGSTOP $(pidof command_name)**..!!. This would end up in error **-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'**.

Comment: A remedy would be command & kill -SIGSTOP $(pidof command_name)

Answer (score 1):

Demo & kludge using **timeout**, (for some reason **timeout** intereprets a '0s' duration as "run forever"), to stop **yes** before it outputs anything:

```
# run 'yes' command, let it print 5 numbered lines, but stop it immediately
timeout -s SIGSTOP .000000001s yes | head -n 5 | cat -n
```

Output (to STDERR):

```
[1]+  Stopped     timeout -s SIGSTOP .000000001s yes | head -n 5 | cat -n
```

Now restart it:

```
fg > /dev/null
```

Output:

```
 1  y
 2  y
 3  y
 4  y
 5  y
```

---

Technique for users stuck with v8.12 or earlier **coreutils**, (pre-2011), wherein **timeout** lacks *sub-second intervals*.  Requires waiting a second.

Wrap the command string in a shell invocation, preceded by a 1s wait -- so **timeout** waits 1 second, and simultaneously, so does the command string.  Total wait time 1 second:

```
timeout -s SIGSTOP 1s sh -c "sleep 1s; yes | head -n 5 | cat -n"
```

Output is the same as before, `fg` is the same too.

Finesse, if waiting even 1 second before sleeping is too much, it can be run in the background like so:

```
timeout -s SIGSTOP 1s sh -c "sleep 1s; yes | head -n 5 | cat -n" &
```

Output (process number will vary):

```
[1] 14601
```

Then after a second, the output will be the same as the previous two **timeout** examples.

Comment: can you kindly give example with command involved in background..?

Comment: OK, the example code now shows how `yes` can be restarted with `fg`.  Perhaps I should have used `seq 5` instead of `yes`...

Comment: It did not work on setup (Distro -RHEL 6.6, bash shell). CMD :`timeout -s SIGSTOP .0000000000000000001s netserver -D -p 11192 -4 102.3.3.215 > /root/results.log 2>&1 & `  Error:`timeout: invalid time interval `.0000000000000000001s'
Try `timeout --help' for more information.`

Comment: Works on 64-bit Lubuntu.  Might be a compiler thing.  I used 21 decimal places just because it worked, but I doubt very many are needed.  Please try fewer zeros, say five or ten..

Comment: on RHEL it takes it only in terms of integers not floats. so minimum i can wait is 1 second..!

Comment: The _coreutils_ NEWS file (its changelog) shows that _timeout_ didn't get sub-second intervals until 2011.  RHEL 6 came out in 2010...

Answer (score 0):

Plainly answering the title.

Pausing a running command, e.g. FFmpeg:

```bash
kill -17 `ps aux | grep -E "\s[f]fmpeg\s" | awk '{print $2}'`
```

Or, even simpler:

```bash
kill -17 `pidof ffmpeg`
```

Use `-17` or `-18`—read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/410089) to know the difference.

I prefer to use `pgrep` as it seems a bit more reliable than `pidof`:

```
kill -17 `pgrep ffmpeg`
```

Or, create your own “command”:

```bash
pid () { ps aux | grep -E "\s$(echo $1 | sed -r 's/(\S)(\S*)/\[\1\]\2/')\s" | awk '{print $2}' }
```

Thus, pausing/resuming becomes simpler:

```bash
$ kill -17 `pid ffmpeg`
$ kill -19 `pid ffmpeg`
```

There's also the `pkill` command:

```bash
pkill -17 -f ffmpeg
```

But, it's less reliable than combining `kill` with `pgrep` or `pid`.

The reason why it's less reliable: the `pkill` command will target **any** process containing *ffmpeg* word—and not only `ffmpeg` processes.